# Reverse the number in a filename

Tags: bash

So it seems that I have made a error when trying to make more readable filestructure. I accidentally named files in the wrong order, and now I need to correct it.

The files are named:

- `001 - file number 1.jpg`
- `001 - file number 2.mp3`
- `002 - file number 3.jpg`
- `002 - file number 4.mp3`
- `003 - file number 5.jpg`
- `003 - file number 6.mp3`

and so on up to I think 800 files in one folder, and 300 in another, its kind of a mess.

The correct order should be:

- `003 - file number 1.jpg`
- `003 - file number 2.mp3`
- `002 - file number 3.jpg`
- `002 - file number 4.mp3`
- `001 - file number 5.jpg`
- `001 - file number 6.mp3`

How can I rename all files, and change the number so it goes the reversed order?

Answer (score 1):

If the reversal is to be performed in your locale's collation order:

```
name=(*.{jpg,mp3})
pfix=("${name[@]%% *}")
for ((i=0,j=${#name[@]}-1; j>=0; i++,j--)); do
  echo mv "${name[i]}" "${pfix[j]} ${name[i]#* }"
done
```

Populates an array with filenames and another with prefixes; loops through both in opposite directions and re-pairs them in reverse order.

Drop `echo` if its output looks good. Might complain that target and the source is the same just once, but that won't cause any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how well will this scale on large amount of files but here it is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s  extglob nullglob

file=(*.@(mp3|jpg))

mapfile -t -d '' files < <(printf '%s\0' "${file[@]}")

mapfile -t -d '' renamed < <(paste -zd ' ' <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]%% *}" | sort -rz ) <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]#* }"))

for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
  echo mv -v "${files[$i]}" "${renamed[$i]}"
done
```

Output

```
    mv -v 001 - file number 1.jpg 003 - file number 1.jpg
    mv -v 001 - file number 2.mp3 003 - file number 2.mp3
    mv -v 002 - file number 3.jpg 002 - file number 3.jpg
    mv -v 002 - file number 4.mp3 002 - file number 4.mp3
    mv -v 003 - file number 5.jpg 001 - file number 5.jpg
    mv -v 003 - file number 6.mp3 001 - file number 6.mp3
```

- It will spit an error message like what @oguz posted.
- `bash4+` only because of `mapfile`
- Also the `-z` on both `paste` and `sort` might be `GNU` only.

Another option if you have the utility `vidir` which you can use your favorite text editor to rename your files. The caveat is it does not support file/path names with newlines.

```
vidir /path/to/files
```

Using your favorite text editor

```
EDITOR=kate vidir /path/to/files
```

If it is the first time you will use `vidir` then I suggest you try it on some test files first. The first column is just the increment of the files/directories don't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Use param `-r` in `sort` →  `sort -r file`